# Execute a thread in a queue only if its field value doesn't match an already running thread

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpoolexecutor

I have a large number of events coming in, and I must run the ones sequentially that have certain matching properties. Let's call this property "color". If I get 3 green events, and 2 yellow events, then I must run all the 3 green events in the order received, so they must be run one at a time. Same goes for the yellow events. If all 3 green events are processed before the first yellow event completes, that's fine, because across colors the order doesn't matter.

Now, I also have a limit to the total number of threads that can be run at once, and there's dozens of colors. So if I get 20 events of 20 different colors, I can't run them all at once. They must be under the thread pool limit. Ideally, **the executor always be running the oldest event first, so long as there is no other event with the same color currently running.**

So, what needs to happen is when it comes time for the ThreadPoolExecutor to dequeue a Runnable, it needs to check to see if there are any other Runnables of the same color. If so, look to the next Runnable in the Queue, until it finally finds one that doesn't have a matching color currently running. Then it will remove that from the Queue, without disturbing the order of any of the other elements in the Queue.

How would I go about implementing this way to dequeue threads in the ThreadPoolExecutor? Or is there another, better, way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Different colors can be processed concurrently, but same colors must be processed serially.

So rather than trying to make all your threads communicate to one another what color they are doing let's just make a dedicated queue for each color, and one thread handling that queue.

So one distributor thread reads the event queue and based on the color of the event posts it on the appropriate queue.

Now you indicate that you can't have as many threads as there are colors, but colors can share a queue. That still guarantees the serial processing of each color.

Comment: Re, "can't have as many threads as colors..." Sounds like you are saying, dedicate one queue to green and yellow, dedicate another to red and blue, etc. Looks  like Basil Borque thought the same. Is that what you meant?

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes, although he demonstrates it as a hardcoded assignment, my intent was only that you have to make sure the same color always gets assigned the same queue. Much like the same hashcode would be assigned the same bucket.

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer I was looking for. I wrap a `ColorRunnable` in a `QueueRunnable`, and then `QueueRunnable` does the logic to figure out which Executor to add the `ColorRunnable` to.

Comment: I also made a separate field that keeps track of what color is assigned to each Executor, and if it runs out of items, it will reassign the color when a new one is added.

Answer (score 1):

The [Answer by bowmore](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76377869/642706) is correct. Here’s some code.

Define your various color tasks as a `Runnable` or `Callable` that implements an interface `hasColor` requiring a method `getColor`. Define an enum `TaskColor` for all possible colors.

Say we have four colors but a limit of two threads. Define two executor service objects, each to handle a pair of our four colors. Make them single-threaded to run tasks one on a time.

```
ExecutorService esGreenYellow = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
ExecutorService esBlueRed = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor() ;
```

Write a method that receives all tasks of type `hasColor`. That method shunts tasks of green or yellow into the first of those two executor services, and tasks of the other two colors into the second executor service.

Comment: This isn't dynamic enough. I want to process in FIFO as much as possible, and if say GreenYellow have 100 events come in each, they will slow each other down when the BlueRed could be idle at the same time. Though, your post gave me an idea on how to do this that I will try to implement. Which is having a queue for everything, then delegating them to a queue for each ExecutorService.]